# Can't create MySQL Trigger with several tables

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I've got a database with 3 tables:

1. `delivery`
2. `company`
3. `details`

The `company` table has a column with ratings from 1 to 10 and if a rating is more than 5 we can understand that this company is reliable and in detail if the price is more than 1000 it is expensive detail.

Table `delivery` is connecting table for `company` and `details` Now I'm trying to create a trigger that will block **Insert** when somebody trying to add in table `delivery` expensive detail with an unreliable company, but I can't understand how to create Trigger using data from different tables.

I'm using MySQL

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_1
BEFORE INSERT
ON delivery
FOR EACH ROW
IF company.rating < 5 AND detail.Det_Price > 1000 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unreliable company';
END IF //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: *`IF company.rating < 5 AND detail.Det_Price > 1000 THEN`* Each mentioned table have a lot of rows... what row do you want the specified values to be taken from? You must execute SELECT from these tables with according WHERE conditions referred to NEW values and check the output.

Comment: SIGNAL will break the insertion - hence the trigger won't allow the delivery row if the company does not match the reliability criteria... but what is the reason in storing this unreliable company at all, or at least in showing it to the client?

Comment: Start by writing a query which does what you want , create procedure to test it, if ok create trigger , if still got a problem publish trigger.

Comment: @P.Salmon I already tried to, but still can’t do it(

Comment: @P.Salmon how I can do insert query with IF statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html paying particular attention to the discussion of NEW. values.

A simple version of the trigger might be like

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_1
BEFORE INSERT
ON delivery
FOR EACH ROW
begin
declare vrating int;
declare vprice  int;

select company.rating into vrating from company where company.id = new.company_id;
select detail.det_price into vprice from detail where detail.? = new.?;
IF vrating < 5 AND vPrice > 1000 THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
   SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unreliable company';
END IF ;
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

but since you didn't publish table definitions I can't tell you exactly how the selects should be.

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE `deal`.`detail` ( `id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `Det_Name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , `Det_Price` INT(255) NOT NULL , `Det_Color` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , `Det_weight` INT(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try it now and send you feedback

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE `deal`.`company` ( `id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `com_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , `com_city` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , `com_addres` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , `rating` INT(255) NULL , NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;```